# How would/do you secure your users details

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

With the wondrous "lulsec", "anonymous" and other interesting parties breaking, decrypting (unless your plain-text Sony) and sharing their horde with the entire web, it begs the question.

**How do you secure your users passwords?**

*I've labeled this C# as I've seen a lot of sites still using things like MD5, which is pretty worthless in a world filled with rainbow tables. Though of course this isn't an issue restricted to that specific language (affects most things); I'm just more interested in responses tackling the Microsoft Stack.*

Comment: That's far too broad a question. Securing data is an absolutely massive topic which cannot be answered in a book, let alone a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I disagree but will reduce the scope to passwords; its an important and relevant topic, and shouldnt be restricted soley to books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html) covers the bulk of what you ask about. MD5 is not worthless if you salt it.

The difference between a salted and unsalted table is that in the former case you effectively have to create a new rainbow table for each unique salt. If they're intent on finding the details of you, and just you, they'll likely be able to do it just as fast as they would with a rainbow table across an unsalted database, but they could not reuse those calculations to get the data of anybody else.

Comment: The problem with salting is in most of the latest breaches (and lots of past ones) both the database and source code is extracted from the system; in which case its simple enough to reproduce a token based on this, and append that to the rainbow-tables ~ processing script.

Comment: Of course creating a unique-salt will slow most things down for someone after a quick hack-n-drop. But hash-speed in MD5 and even SHA1 works in the favour of the hacker rather.

Comment: This is not the case. If you assign a random salt to each user it doesn't matter whether they have your code, your database or your physical server, it'll still increase the complexity of a succesful attack across the entire database exponentially with respect to the length of that salt. Read the article.

Comment: You can MD5 500 times if you're concerned about its speed. That turns it into a 'slow' algorithm...

Comment: Well ye' thats one way of dealing with it and is comparable to the blowfish cost parameter.

Comment: That article is great; I tend to peruse OWASP but I hadnt seen that guys blog before; ta.

Comment: Interesting post on why you should use BCrypt over MD5 etal http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/